# Keys in Keyboard not working intermintently

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard

My Laptop is Dell Latitute E6530 (3.0GHz processor, 8GB RAM, 64bit Arch.)

I dual boot my laptop Ubuntu 20.10 and Window 10.
All keys works just find in the windows.
However, in the Ubuntu, the keys randomnly will stop working and
without any repairs, they will starts to work again.

I have tried update and upgrade to latest distro but it seem no solution.
Please, any help?